# Why am I receiving Oracle error-ORA-01790 when trying to join to tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, case

I have two tables I am using to join together to produce a new table that contains the sum of two fields called "forecast" and "closed", along with its metadata.

The issue I am having
is that since in I have a condition **where if the value is 'Green' then insert a '-' sign**. Intuitively, when I do a sum on that column, it gives me an error of **"expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"**. Is there a way to write a case
statement within my script to circumvent that or a different solution?

**Table1:**

```
chart_date | FLAG | MESSAGING | FORECAST  | CLOSED
21-JUL-20     NULL   BLUE           10       10
22-JUL-20     NULL   BLUE           10       20
23-JUL-20     NULL   BLUE           10       106
21-JUL-20     NULL   GREEN          -        356
22-JUL-20     NULL   GREEN          -        457
23-JUL-20     NULL   GREEN          -        65
21-JUL-20     NULL   RED            5        13
22-JUL-20     NULL   RED            5        223
23-JUL-20     NULL   RED            5        11
```

**Table2- which holds our static data:**

```
chart_date | FLAG | HEADER     | METRIC  | FORECAST
20-JUL-20     1      TYPE        BLUE        0
20-JUL-20      8      TYPE       GREEN       0  
20-JUL-20      9      TYPE       RED         0
```

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
with t2
as (
select 
b.flag,
b.metric messaging,  
NVL(a.INCOMING,0)   INCOMING,
case when b.metric in 
('GREEN'
) then  '-' 
else to_char((NVL(round(a.Forecast,0),0))) end as Forecast  
from
DB1.TABLE2 b
inner join
DB1.TABLE1 a
on (a.messaging=b.metric)
where b.header='MESSAGING'
and a.messaging in ('RED','GREEN','BLUE' )
)
select flag,messaging, SUM(NVL(INCOMING,0)) AS CLOSED_SUM, SUM(NVL(FORECAST,0)) as FORECAST_SUM
from t2  group by flag, messaging, FORECAST 
union
select 
a.flag,a.metric,0,'0'
from DB1.TABLE2 a
left join
t2
on (t2.messaging=a.metric)
where t2.messaging is null
and a.header like 'MESSAGING'
and a.metric  in ('RED','GREEN','BLUE' )
```

**This is the error message I get:**

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 24 Column: 57
```

As you can see, it outputs each type by its date but it doesn't group then together to create a sum column.

**This is the Desired Output I want:**

```
FLAG | MESSAGING | FORECAST_SUM  | CLOSED_SUM 
1      RED           15                247
8      BLUE          30                136
9      GREEN         -                 878
```

No duplicates, just each type and its sum of the forecast field and closed_sum field This seems like a somewhat easy fix but I have been debugging for hours but to no avail, so any ideas or suggestions will help!

Comment: Where's `Line: 24 Column: 57`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the data types in the union need to be matching. I see in the code the following:

```
a.flag,a.metric,0,'0'
```

Can you try this below to see if it works?

```
a.flag,a.metric,0,0
```

Comment: @mali_the That's a new error, this answer seems to be the solution to the error in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I simply joined two tables with inner join then calculate the sum of `forecast` and `closed` columns of `Table1` then grouped by `chart_date ,flag,header,metric` columns from Table2. Please check.

Query:

```
select b.chart_date ,b.flag,b.header,b.metric,sum(a.forecast)forcast_sum,sum(a.closed)closed_sum
from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.messaging=b.metric
group by b.chart_date ,b.flag,b.header,b.metric
```

Output:

| CHART_DATE | FLAG | HEADER | METRIC | FORCAST_SUM | CLOSED_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-JUL-20 | 1 | TYPE | BLUE | 30 | 136 |
| 20-JUL-20 | 8 | TYPE | GREEN | - | 878 |
| 20-JUL-20 | 9 | TYPE | RED | 15 | 247 |

Comment: forecast sum green value should be - not 0

Comment: What's the data type of FORECAST  column of Table1?

Comment: data type is NUMBER

Comment: This answer explains nothing

Comment: @mali_the my data type was wrong. I have changed the datatype and now the result is what you were looking for. Please let me know if I got your logic right.